# jQuery hide ul header when all entries are deleted

Tags: jquery

I'm a noob with jQuery...and I hope I've explained this well enough; I have a `<ul>` header that appears when I've added an entry to a dynamically created list using `$.post`.  Each entry added has a delete/edit button associated with it.

Header is this:

```
<ul class="header">
    <li>Month</li>
    <li>Year</li>
    <li>Cottage</li>
</ul>
```

My dynamic list  that is created:

```
<ul class="addedItems">    
    <li>Month</li>
    <li>Year</li>
    <li>Cottage</li>
    <li><span class="edit">edit</span></li>
    <li><span class="del">delete</span></li>
</ul>


This all looks like this:

Month        Year        Cottage    <--this appears after I've added an entry
--------------------------------       and I want it to stick around unless 
                                       all items are deleted.


Dec          1990        Fir        edit/delete  <--entries   
Jan          2000        Willow     edit/delete
```

My question is:  Is there some kind of conditional that I can use with jQuery to hide the `class="header"` if all the items are deleted?  I've read up on conditional statements like `is` and `not` with jq but I'm not really understanding how they work.  All of the items in `class="addedItems"` is stored in `data` produced by JSON.

This is the delete function:

```
  $(".del").live("click", function(){
      var del = this;
      var thisVal = $(del).val();
      $.post("delete.php", { dirID : thisVal },
       function(data){
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to DELETE this entry?") == true) {
           if(data.success) {
            //hide the class="header" here somwhere??
            $(del).parents(".addedItems").hide();
           } else if(data.error) {
            // throw error if item does not delete
           }
         }
       }, "json");
        return false;
    }); //end of .del function
```

Here is the delete.php

```
    <?php

    if($_POST) {


      $data['delID'] = $_POST['dirID'];

      $query = "DELETE from //tablename WHERE dirID = '{$data['delID']}' LIMIT 1";

      $result = $db->query($query);

      if($result) {
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = "Entry was successfully removed.";
      } else {
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['message'] = "Item could not be deleted.";
      }

      echo json_encode($data);
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need an each-function :

```
$(del).parents('.header').each(function(){
  if ( $(this).children('.addedItems:visible').length == 0 )
  {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

As soon as called this tiny script will hide any UL of .header without any children.

place this script after your `$(del).parents(".addedItems").hide();`

Comment: man...still no luck.  Can you put an `each` inside of a `live` click function?  Shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: I think I got it.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to DELETE this entry?") == true) {
    if(data.success) {
        //hide the class="header" here somwhere??
        $(del).parents(".addedItems").hide();

        //CHECK IF THERE ARE NOT ANY LI ITEMS IN UL
        if($("ul.addedItems li").length==0){
            $("ul.header").hide();//HIDE HEADER LIST
        }

    } else if(data.error) {
      // throw error if item does not delete
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea..wasn't really aware that you could do this..hmm.

Comment: I guess your code still won't work. Because the length is > 0 as the list elements are only hidden and not removed.

Comment: as @Scott has already figured out you can add `.is(":visible").length`

Answer (score 0):

Based on some of the answers here, this is what I came up with:

```
    if($("ul.header").siblings("ul.addedItems").is(":visible")) {
    } else {
      $("ul.header").hide();
    }
```

Thanks to everyone for the insight.